# Добавление товара в корзину в reactjs приложении

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Я изучаю reactj, создавая самое простое приложение-магазин, используя react hooks, без редакса. Не работает функция добавления товаров в корзину. В родительском компоненте 'MainPage' находятся карточки товаров. При нажатии на кнопку карточки, в компонент 'Basket' должен добавляться компонент 'AddedProduct' с соответствующими данными конкретного товара, взятыми из массива объектов 'productsDataArray'. Ниже привожу компоненты, имеющие отношение к добавлению товаров. Думаю, проблема в функциях 'updateContent' или 'clickBtn'. Помогите решить проблему добавления товаров.

```
export const MainPage = props => {                 {/* parent component with product cards*/} 
   const [basketContent, changeBasketContent] = useState([]);  

 const updateContent = (product) => {
     const addedItems = productsDataArray.filter(item => item.id == product.id);
          return (
             <div>                      
                <AddedProducts productData = {product} />                                
             </div>                                           
          );                   
     changeBasketContent(addedItems);         
 };

 const clickBtn = (e) => {     
    updateContent(e.target);
 };  

       return ( 
         <div> 
            <div id = 'productSection'> 
               {productsDataArray.map(item => {
                 return (
                  <div key = {item.id}>
                     ProductCard productData = {item}
                     clickBtn = {clickBtn}                                        
                   />             
                  </div>  
                   );
                 }                 
              )}
            </div>
            <Basket/>
       </div> 
    );
  };

export const ProductCard = props => {     
   const {productData, clickBtn} = props;           
     return (  
      <div id = 'productCard' style = {{width: '300px'}}>
           <img src = {productData.photo} alt = {productData.name} height = "200" />
           <div>
              <h6>{productData.name}</h6>
              <div>    
                 <p>Price: {productData.price}</p>
                 <button type = 'button' onClick = {clickBtn}>                               
                        Add to basket
                 </button>              
              </div>                   
           </div>
         </div>       
       );
   };        
   
export const Basket = props => {        
 const {basketContent} = props;  
    return (  
    <section id = 'basket-bloc'>       
        <div id = "basket-main">        
             {basketContent}       
        </div>         
    </section>
   );
}; 

export const AddedProduct = props => {
   const {productData} = props;    
     return (  
      <div id = 'addedProduct'>         
         <div id = 'product-img-small' className = 'basketItem'>
         <img src = {productData.photo} width = '50'
             alt = {productData.name} />
         </div>
        <div id ='product-name' className = 'basketItem'>
           <p>{productData.name}</p>         
        </div> 
     </div>
  );
};                                                  

export const productsDataArray = [
 { 
   id : 1.1, 
   name: "Title1",
   price: "10$",
   photo: img1     
 },
 { 
   id : 1.2,  
   name: "Title2",
   price: "20$",
   photo: img2     
 },
 { 
   id : 1.3,  
   name: "Title3",
   price: "30$",
   photo: img3     
 },
 { 
  id : 1.4,   
  name: "Title4",
  price: "25$",
  photo: img4    
 }          
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const updateContent = (product) => {
     const addedItems = productsDataArray.filter(item => item.id == product.id);
          return (
             <div>                      
                <AddedProducts productData = {product} />                                
             </div>                                           
          );                   
     changeBasketContent(addedItems);         
 };

 const clickBtn = (e) => {     
    updateContent(e.target);
 };  

<button type = 'button' onClick = {clickBtn}>                               
     Add to basket
</button>
```

Вся проблема заключается в данном участке кода: на событие onClick у элемента button, вы вызываете callback clickBtn, который вызывает функцию updateContent, передавая в качестве значения аргумента product e.target, но только e.target - это кнопка и он не укажет в качестве product магическом образом нужный объект.

В качестве верного варианта, вам нужно передать стрелочную функцию в свойство onClick кнопки, где вы вызовите clickBtn, передав в качестве аргумента product productData. Небольшой совет по именованию в React: функция clickBtn не понятно за что отвечает, а updateContent не понятно, какой контент обновляет, намного лучше будет переименовать clickBtn на handleAddProductToCart или onAddProductToCart, а updateContent в addProductToCart или что-то в этом духе.

```js
 const handleAddProductToCart = (productData) => {
     const addedItems = productsDataArray.filter(item => item.id == product.id);
          return (
             <div>                      
                <AddedProducts productData={productData} />                                
             </div>                                           
          );                   
     changeBasketContent(addedItems);         
 };

export const ProductCard = props => {     
   const {productData, clickBtn} = props;           
     return (  
      <div id = 'productCard' style = {{width: '300px'}}>
           <img src = {productData.photo} alt = {productData.name} height = "200" />
           <div>
              <h6>{productData.name}</h6>
              <div>    
                 <p>Price: {productData.price}</p>
                 <button 
                     type = 'button' 
                     onClick = {() => handleAddProductToCart(productData)}
                 >                               
                        Add to basket
                 </button>              
              </div>                   
           </div>
         </div>       
       );
   };
```

Я сейчас заметил странность в вашем коде:

```js
 const updateContent = (product) => {
     const addedItems = productsDataArray.filter(item => item.id == product.id);
          return (
             <div>                      
                <AddedProducts productData = {product} />                                
             </div>                                           
          );
     // код после return не будет работать.               
     changeBasketContent(addedItems);         
 };
```

Я не совсем понимаю, что здесь должно было быть, по этой причине написал простенький пример желаемого вами результата на codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-lovelace-qjknv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/index.js

Очень прошу вас, если вы хотите что-то еще узнать поэтому вопросу, обязательно отвечайте мне, а, если вы бы хотели иметь того, у кого вы могли бы спросить что-либо по React, Webpack, TypeScript, Node.js, то вот вам мой vk: https://vk.com/lucien_glue.

Надеюсь, я был для вас хоть сколько-то полезным.

Comment: Я попытаюсь разобраться в коде, на который вы дали ссылку и применить к своему. О результатах сообщу. А что касается изменений, написанных вами выше, то они приводят к ошибке.

Comment: @Irina, минимальный функционал на основе вашего примера https://codesandbox.io/embed/awesome-platform-p32m7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Коды по Вашим ссылкам помогли мне добавлять и удалять товар в корзину. Однако, я не совсем понимаю, как работает добавление в корзину. Например, почему здесь мы  в массив добавляем вторым параметром productID :                                                                               
            const handleAddProductToBasket = productID => {
                    setBasketProducts([...basketProducts, productID]);
              };

Comment: @Irina, массив добавленных товаров в корзину, это массив id-шников товаров. Если мы будет добавлять в массив корзины все данные товара, то это будет дублировать данные, а в этом нет смысла, т.к. мы можем найти все нужные нам данные по его id в массиве товаров.

Comment: Какую роль играет productID в состоянии setBasketProducts([...basketProducts, productID])? Мы ведь потом указываем его в описании функции?

Comment: Здесь мы добавляем productID в корзину. какой productID? Их же много и добавлять их должен пользователь, нажимая на кнопку, а не мы в коде. Если мы уберем в setBacketProducts([...basketProducts, productID]) productID, то у нас получится код setBasketProducts(basketProducts), а это абсолютно бессмысленный код.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы товары в корзине не дублировались? Если товар уже добавлен, то повторное нажатие на кнопку не должно снова его добавлять. В вашем примере они добавляются без ограничений.

Comment: @Irina, в самом первом моем примере это реализовано.
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-lovelace-qjknv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/index.js

Comment: Так как вы предложили свою помощь, я хотела бы ещё спросить, если можно: я  добавила функцию регулирования количества товара в корзине. Проблема в том, что при увеличении количества конкретного товара в корзине, увеличивается количество всех добавленных товаров, а мне нужно каждый увеличивать индивидуально. Вот ссылка на код, в котором я к вашему примеру добавила эту функцию.     https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-mendel-c6ofv?file=/src/App.js      Как мне её изменить, чтобы она работала правильно? (Функцию уменьшения товара я там не писала, так как с ней проблем не было).

Comment: В массив корзины вы добавляейте не id-шник товара, а объект типа { id, count } и при нажатии на увелечения количества товара вам нужно найти нужный товар по id и увеличить поле count.

Не понятно зачем, вы передаете компоненту Card(в корзине) два props - prodQuantity и increaseQuantity

Comment: Я не поняла, как написать правильно эту функцию. А два props мне необходимы, так как prodQuantity - это переменная счётчика с начальным состоянием "1":                                               const [prodQuantity, setProdQuantity] = useState(1);                                                              increaseQuantity - переменная, меняющая состояние счётчика:                              const increaseQuantity = productID => {          
      setProdQuantity(prodQuantity + 1);
   };      они обе используются в корзине.

Comment: @Irina, я понимаю, что они используются, но зачем компоненту Card то передовать?

Comment: Я не планировала передавать их Card. Значит, в вашем коде я не нашла, куда добавлять,там все компоненты вместе, трудно разобрать. У меня корзина в отдельном файле, и я добавляла в корзину. Проблема не в этом, а в том, что я не поняла, как правильно написать функцию увеличения количества на 1 при нажатии на кнопку +. И с  этим я просила помочь. Я не могу разобраться, как работать с отдельными элементами добавленных товаров, как получить к ним доступ. И для начала мне нужно понять, как работает функция, о которой я упоминала. Надеюсь, что вы подскажете.

Comment: Алгоритм таков:
**1)** В вашем массиве корзины теперь хранятся не просто id-шники товаров, а обьект типа:
`
{
  id
  count
}
`

**2)** Нажимая на кнопку "+" вы передаете id-шник условной функции, вызывая ее, скажем handleIncrementProductCount.

**3)** Дальше, handleIncrementProductCount проходит массив корзины и ищет тот товар, id-шник которого был передан.

**4)** Найдя его, мы устанавливаем новое состояние корзины, где у нас прежнее состояние корзины, но у найденного объекта увеличиваем count на 1.

Comment: @Irina, жаль, что вы выбрали комментари stackoverflow. Здесь очень проблемно общаться и, к тому же, мы все дальше и дальше уходим от начального вопроса, что нарушает не только правила stackoverflow, но еще и смысл его сущности.

Comment: Скажите, где для Вас удобнее общаться.

Comment: VK, facebook, telegram, discord, что-нибудь из этого

Comment: Хорошо, я воспользуюсь ссылкой на VK, которую вы дали выше. В telegrame вам, возможно, будет не очень удобно.

Comment: @Irina, хорошо.